# How to Programmatically add an empty Block to every post on wordpress site?

Tags: posts, block-editor

I am looking for a way to add add an empty paragraph Block to every existing post on wordpress site Programmatically or through backend MySQL query.
I want to keep this block updating in future through some automation method
Can you help ?.

Comment: Which block do you want to add? What do you mean by “empty block”?

Comment: An empty paragraph block.

Comment: Do you actually need this to be in the post content? It sounds like this belongs on the page template instead.

Comment: And presumably if you're going to "keep ... updating this block"  then it's not always  going to be an empty paragraph, is it?

Comment: Yes, @JacobPeattie . But i will update them via DB backend update query since they will all be first block, it may be easier to have same identifier for update